# Execute PowerShell without leaving gVim

Tags: powershell, vim, plugins

I'm currently using vim to edit several PowerShell files, but I'm finding it to be a real pain to always have to go back to my PowerShell console to run the scripts.

Is there a plugin that would allow me to either a) run the current script and/or b) run selected text. I've seen videos where such thing is done for other languages, but I can't for the life of me find the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://juliankay.com/development/setting-up-vim-to-work-with-powershell/) gives a pretty straightforward description on how to do this. You are wanting to run Powershell through VIM correct?